# what is the one point compactification of R?

Tags: general-topology

It is said that the one point compactification of R is a circle. But how do i show it? I know it suffices to show R is homeomorphic to a punctured circle but how can i prove it?

Comment: You can search: Alexandroff compactification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension

Comment: SImply consider $\Bbb{R} \to S^1$ defined by $t \mapsto e^{2i \arctan t}$.

Comment: @Novati: Thanks i will check it up

Comment: @Crostul: That is not even a surjection

Comment: It's a surjection onto $S^1 \setminus \{ -1 \}$.

Answer (score 12):

Pictorially, you can imagine $\mathbb R$ to be a tangent of the circle at point $x \in S^1$. Now for each point $y \in \mathbb R$ imagine a segment joining $y$ and $-x$; $z$ be the point of intersection of this segment and the circle. The correspondence $y \mapsto z$ is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and $S^1 - \{-x\}$.

The nice thing about this construction is that it is generalizable!

[image: homeomorphism between real line and punctured circle]

Comment: this is a quite old answer, but nonetheless; shouldn't it read, for any point $y\in\mathbb R$ instead of $y\in S^1$?

Comment: @RScrlli Yes. Fixed it.